# code for min max using array in java without any import

Tags: java, arrays

```
class test3
{
    public static void main(String[] z)
    {
        int a[]={123456789};    
        for(int i=0;i<=a.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("hello");
            if(a[i]<=a[i])             //is this a right way
               System.out.println("min"+a[i]);
            if(a[i]>=a[i-1])           //is this a right way
               System.out.println("max="+a[i]);
            else
               System.out.println("error");
            }
         }
     }
```

Got the following exception in thread "main"

`java.lang.arrayindexoutofbound exception -1 at test3.main(test3.java:9)`

Comment: This code has so many problems, I don't know where to start.

Comment: Please go to [The Java Tutorials: Learning the Java Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html)

Comment: sry :P @OliCharlesworth m just a biginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankly your code has many issues, but if I understand your objective you want something like

```
int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }; // <-- declare an array.
int min = a[a.length - 1];               // <-- set an initial min.
int max = a[0];                          // <-- set an initial max.
if (min > max) {                         // <-- check if they're reversed,
  min = a[0];                            //     if so swap them.
  max = a[a.length - 1];
}
for (int i = 1; i < a.length - 1; i++) { // <-- loop
  if (a[i] < min)                        // <-- is a[i] less then min,
    min = a[i];                          //     if so update min.
  if (a[i] > max)                        // <-- is a[i] greater then max,
    max = a[i];                          //     if so update max.
}
System.out.printf("min = %d, max = %d%n", min, max);
```

Comment: wt if i declares int min or max zero.. lyk int min=0;

Comment: You'd need to change the bounds of the loop above.

Comment: can u explan it by simple example ..?

Comment: Actually, never mind it wouldn't work. 0 is less then everything in your array, so min would be zero your way.

Comment: ohk.. thnks sir.. by the way m working on my programing..

Comment: will u suggest some programing ques to improve in array.. and base in java

Answer (score 0):

use the following methods to find max and min.

For MAX:

```
public static int getMaxValue(int[] numbers){
  int maxValue = numbers[0];
  for(int i=1;i < numbers.length;i++){
    if(numbers[i] > maxValue){
      maxValue = numbers[i];
    }
  }
  return maxValue;
}
```

For MIN:

```
public static int getMinValue(int[] numbers){
  int minValue = numbers[0];
  for(int i=1;i<numbers.length;i++){
    if(numbers[i] < minValue){
      minValue = numbers[i];
    }
  }
  return minValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] z)
    {
        int a[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};//first error initialize the array like this
        int min =0;
        int max =0;
        min = a[0];//1
        for(int i=1;i<a.length;i++)//2
        {
            if(a[i]<min)
            {
                min =a[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("min "+min);
        max = a[0];//3
        for(int i=1;i<a.length;i++)//4
        {
            if(a[i]>max)
            {
                max =a[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("max : "+max);
    }
```

1.initialize the variable min to value the array contains at a[0]

2.Iterate over the array and check if array contains value less then initialize if yes then assign that value to min and finally display min

3.initialize the variable max to value the array contains at a[0]

4.Iterate over the array and check if array contains value greater then initialize if yes then assign that value to max and finally display max